# Sencha Touch nested formpanel height issue

Tags: sencha-touch-2

While building a view I tried to nest a formpanel followed by a panel in a panel.

So basically there is a nested structure like this:

`Ext.Panel`
`--Ext.form.Panel`
`--Ext.Panel`

The problem is, that the formpanel has no height. It would be nice if the formpanel would get the height it needs. Like height: auto in CSS.

Any ideas?

The code is the following:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.MyView', {
    extend: 'Ext.Panel',
    xtype: 'myview',

    config : {
        scrollable: true,
        items : [
            {
                xtype: 'formpanel',
                items: [
                    {
                        html: 'Content in formpanel'
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                xtype: 'panel',

                items: [
                    {
                        html: "Content in panel"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can try using `layout` and `flex` properties like this:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.MyView', {
extend: 'Ext.Panel',
xtype: 'myview',

config : {
    scrollable: true,
    layout: 'vbox',
    defaults: {flex: 1},
    items : [
        {
            xtype: 'formpanel',
            items: [
                {
                    html: 'Content in formpanel'
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            xtype: 'panel',

            items: [
                {
                    html: "Content in panel"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
});
```

You can learn more from this [video](http://www.sencha.com/learn/intro-to-layouts-in-sencha-touch-2) about layout in Sencha Touch 2. Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

To display formpanel (Ext.form.Panel, Sencha Touch 2.3+) correctly inside other container you need to add `scrollable: null` property. See example

```
{
    xtype: 'formpanel',
    scrollable: null,         
    items: [
        ...
    ]
}
```